# Add numeric at end of filename if filename exist in media upload directory

Tags: php, wordpress, file-upload

```
 $uploaddir  = wp_upload_dir();
 $file       = $_FILES['panpdf'];
 $uploadfile = $uploaddir['path'] . '/' . basename($file['name']);

 move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $uploadfile);
 $filename    = basename($uploadfile);
 $wp_filetype = wp_check_filetype(basename($filename), null);
 $attachment  = array(
                   'post_mime_type' => $wp_filetype['type'],
                   'post_title' => preg_replace('/\.[^.]+$/', '', $filename),
                    'post_content' => '',
                    'post_status' => 'inherit',
                    'menu_order' => $_i + 1000
                                );
 $update_img  = wp_insert_attachment($attachment, $uploadfile);
```

This work fine and upload file but it upload duplicate, I want to add number at end of filename if filename already exist in upload directory. How I achieve this . Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

Append the time stamp to you file name as per below -

```
$dateTime = new DateTime('now', new DateTimeZone('Asia/Kolkata'));  
$fileName = $file['name']."_".$dateTime;
```

And then pass this file name.